# 新規phpファイルがxamppで読み込めない

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, xampp

ubuntuにxamppを入れたのですが、lamppフォルダに新規ファイルを保存するもObject Not Foundというエラーが発生します。
phpファイルを、htdocs内に保存していますし、lsで確認したところhtdocs内にファイルが存在することを確認できました。
ダウンロードしたときに、元々入っているファイルはきちんと読めますし、Apacheとデータベースも起動しています。

ファイルの編集権限による問題かと思い、確認してみましたが未だ問題解決ならず。

このような場合には、どのような原因が考えられるでしょうか。お願いします。

Comment: apacheの設定の変更はしていますか？変更している場合はどのような変更をしたか追記していただけるとありがたいです。

Comment: Apacheのログも確認してみるとヒントがあるかもしれません。

Comment: もう一点念のため、必ずしも「編集権限」は必要ないはずで、「実行権限」や「読み取り権限」を確認すべきかと。`ls -l`の結果を貼ってもらってもよいかもしれません。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。xamppを入れる前にターミナルからApacheをダウンロードしていました。もしかするとそちらが原因でしょうか？

Comment: XAMPP付属のApacheと、個別に入れたApacheの2つが存在している状態で、今現在は恐らく個別に入れたApacheが起動しているのでしょう(ドキュメントルートも`/var/www/html`)。 / 可能であればApache単体をアンイストールしてからXAMPPのApacheを起動し、意図したとおりPHPページが表示できるか試してみてください。

Comment: わかりました。アンインストールをやってみます。